Xcode Arguments Passed On Launch won't load
I am building and running a simple Open MPI C application.
In order to run it, I configured the run process in this way:\

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info -> Executable -> Other... -> /path/to/mpiexec
Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Arguments Passed On Launch -> -np 4 "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"

Now, instead of the hardcoded "4" as the number of processes, I want to specify an environment variable (like the already existing BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR and EXECUTABLE_NAME environment variables), so I enter in Environment Variables NUM_PROCS as Name and 4 as Value.
Thus, I write in Arguments Passed On Launch the whole quoted string:
"-np" "$(NUM_PROCS)" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)".
And Xcode can't read the NUM_PROCS environment variable (despite I can easily read it in the C program by a getenv("NUM_PROCS")!), in fact, it runs the default number of processes of my system (12).
I tried in a very large number the different ways of writing arguments (every string on a new line, with quotes, without quotes, ...), but none worked as I expected.
M3 Pro, macOS Sequoia 15.0.1
Xcode 16.0

i do not have a setup for xcode, or any apple products. it is just a guess, maybe there should be space between -np and $num_procs? it is a speculation, but can you check that -np 4 have space between switch and the argument.

@user14063792468 Thank you for the advice, but didn't work.
